# Function getAccountBalance() doesn't work

Tags: nearprotocol, near, nearprotocol-validator

I am creating examples to share with another developers but i try to keep for now very simple the code, all the basic functions  are working:

I am using the oficial documentation.[LINK](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#connect)

```js
account.deleteAccount()
account.getAccountDetails()
account.createAccount()
```

etc... but this function:

```js
account.getAccountBalance();
```

Send me a error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "storage_amount _per_byte" )
at Account.getAccountBalance (VM3453 near-api-is.is:346)
at async main.is: 46
```

[image]

+++++UPDATE++++++

```js
const CONTRACT_NAME = 'josedlujan.testnet'; /* TODO: fill this in! */
const config = {
    nodeUrl: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
    //deps: {
        keyStore: new nearApi.keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore(),
    //},
    networkId: 'testnet',
        nodeUrl: 'https://rpc.testnet.near.org',
    contractName: CONTRACT_NAME,
    walletUrl: 'https://wallet.testnet.near.org',
    helperUrl: 'https://helper.testnet.near.org'


};

async function () {
    window.near = await nearApi.connect(config);
    console.log(near)
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // here you have access to `near-api-js` and a valid connection object `near`
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    window.walletConnection = new nearApi.WalletConnection(near);
    console.log(window.walletConnection)

    // Initializing our contract APIs by contract name and configuration.
    window.contract = await new nearApi.Contract(window.walletConnection.account(), near.contractName, {
        // View methods are read-only – they don't modify the state, but usually return some value
        viewMethods: ['get_num'],
        // Change methods can modify the state, but you don't receive the returned value when called
        changeMethods: ['increment', 'decrement', 'reset'],
        // Sender is the account ID to initialize transactions.
        // getAccountId() will return empty string if user is still unauthorized
        sender: window.walletConnection.getAccountId()
    });

 window.account = await near.account(walletConnection.getAccountId());
    console.log(window.account);

 const balance = await window.account.getAccountBalance();
    console.log(balance);
```

Comment: Where do you create an account, and where do you call `account.getAccountBalance();` in the updated code example?

Comment: hi @John i add the code you mentioned

Comment: It looks like it should be working as far as I can tell. Which version of `near-api-js` are you using? Have you tried using the latest version (0.44.2)?

Comment: Also, as mentioned in Sherif's answer, try to log the content of `const protocolConfig = await account.connection.provider.experimental_protocolConfig({finality: 'final',});` and see what you get. You can also try to clear `localStorage` (not sure it'll help though)

Comment: i am using cdn @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is the documentation is some documents refers to different versions of the API, the first documentation that I consult uses API 36 with which I show the error, in another example as I paste on the screen they use version 41:
[image]
I had to look for the last ncd on my own and use version 44. [LINK](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/near-api-js?path=dist)

The recommendation is always be careful with the versions some documentation **needs an update.**

Be careful when you find specific errors with values of the variables that are not parameters that are requested since it is very likely that the documentation you use is not updated, thanks Sherif for the support and John too.

[NCD](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/near-api-js?path=dist)

Answer (score 1):

while trying to understand what may be breaking, this is what I did ...

#### (1) look at the source code

this is the code you are running when calling that method.  I found it by searching for the string "getAccountBalance" in the [`near-api-js`](https://github.com/near/near-api-js) repo because I see you're running in a JavaScript context and I know that NEAR wraps its API with `near-api-js` to make life easier for JavaScript devs.

[account.getAccountBalance()](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/fd6d643dd9f0d4815a5f14b0525750e86433c862/src/account.ts#L605-L622)

```js
async getAccountBalance(): Promise < AccountBalance > {
  const protocolConfig = await this.connection.provider.experimental_protocolConfig({ finality: 'final' });
  const state = await this.state();

  const costPerByte = new BN(protocolConfig.runtime_config.storage_amount_per_byte);
  const stateStaked = new BN(state.storage_usage).mul(costPerByte);
  const staked = new BN(state.locked);
  const totalBalance = new BN(state.amount).add(staked);
  const availableBalance = totalBalance.sub(BN.max(staked, stateStaked));

  return {
    total: totalBalance.toString(),
    stateStaked: stateStaked.toString(),
    staked: staked.toString(),
    available: availableBalance.toString()
  };
}
```

the first line in the function calls `experimental_protocolConfig`

```js
await this.connection.provider.experimental_protocolConfig({ finality: 'final' });
```

#### (2) test it in pieces

I can take each piece of this function and call it one by one from the REPL available in NEAR CLI and check what it returns

first, start the repl with your account in context

```sh
near repl --accountId sherif.testnet
```

then, call the method

```js
await account.getAccountBalance()
```

and the result is fine for me

```json
{
  total: '21795471561668895374325524265',
  stateStaked: '212510000000000000000000',
  staked: '0',
  available: '21795259051668895374325524265'
}
```

then, call the method

```js
await account.connection.provider.experimental_protocolConfig({ finality: 'final'})
```

and you'll see the return value

```json
{
  "protocol_version": 50,
  "genesis_time": "2020-07-31T03:39:42.911378Z",
  "chain_id": "testnet",
  "genesis_height": 42376888,
  "num_block_producer_seats": 200,
  "num_block_producer_seats_per_shard": [
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200
  ],
  "avg_hidden_validator_seats_per_shard": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  "dynamic_resharding": false,
  "protocol_upgrade_stake_threshold": [
    4,
    5
  ],
  "epoch_length": 43200,
  "gas_limit": 1000000000000000,
  "min_gas_price": "5000",
  "max_gas_price": "10000000000000000000000",
  "block_producer_kickout_threshold": 80,
  "chunk_producer_kickout_threshold": 90,
  "online_min_threshold": [
    90,
    100
  ],
  "online_max_threshold": [
    99,
    100
  ],
  "gas_price_adjustment_rate": [
    1,
    100
  ],
  "runtime_config": {
    "storage_amount_per_byte": "10000000000000000000",
    "transaction_costs": {
      "action_receipt_creation_config": {
        "send_sir": 108059500000,
        "send_not_sir": 108059500000,
        "execution": 108059500000
      },
      "data_receipt_creation_config": {
        "base_cost": {
          "send_sir": 36486732312,
          "send_not_sir": 36486732312,
          "execution": 36486732312
        },
        "cost_per_byte": {
          "send_sir": 17212011,
          "send_not_sir": 17212011,
          "execution": 17212011
        }
      },
      "action_creation_config": {
        "create_account_cost": {
          "send_sir": 99607375000,
          "send_not_sir": 99607375000,
          "execution": 99607375000
        },
        "deploy_contract_cost": {
          "send_sir": 184765750000,
          "send_not_sir": 184765750000,
          "execution": 184765750000
        },
        "deploy_contract_cost_per_byte": {
          "send_sir": 6812999,
          "send_not_sir": 6812999,
          "execution": 6812999
        },
        "function_call_cost": {
          "send_sir": 2319861500000,
          "send_not_sir": 2319861500000,
          "execution": 2319861500000
        },
        "function_call_cost_per_byte": {
          "send_sir": 2235934,
          "send_not_sir": 2235934,
          "execution": 2235934
        },
        "transfer_cost": {
          "send_sir": 115123062500,
          "send_not_sir": 115123062500,
          "execution": 115123062500
        },
        "stake_cost": {
          "send_sir": 141715687500,
          "send_not_sir": 141715687500,
          "execution": 102217625000
        },
        "add_key_cost": {
          "full_access_cost": {
            "send_sir": 101765125000,
            "send_not_sir": 101765125000,
            "execution": 101765125000
          },
          "function_call_cost": {
            "send_sir": 102217625000,
            "send_not_sir": 102217625000,
            "execution": 102217625000
          },
          "function_call_cost_per_byte": {
            "send_sir": 1925331,
            "send_not_sir": 1925331,
            "execution": 1925331
          }
        },
        "delete_key_cost": {
          "send_sir": 94946625000,
          "send_not_sir": 94946625000,
          "execution": 94946625000
        },
        "delete_account_cost": {
          "send_sir": 147489000000,
          "send_not_sir": 147489000000,
          "execution": 147489000000
        }
      },
      "storage_usage_config": {
        "num_bytes_account": 100,
        "num_extra_bytes_record": 40
      },
      "burnt_gas_reward": [
        3,
        10
      ],
      "pessimistic_gas_price_inflation_ratio": [
        103,
        100
      ]
    },
    "wasm_config": {
      "ext_costs": {
        "base": 264768111,
        "contract_compile_base": 35445963,
        "contract_compile_bytes": 216750,
        "read_memory_base": 2609863200,
        "read_memory_byte": 3801333,
        "write_memory_base": 2803794861,
        "write_memory_byte": 2723772,
        "read_register_base": 2517165186,
        "read_register_byte": 98562,
        "write_register_base": 2865522486,
        "write_register_byte": 3801564,
        "utf8_decoding_base": 3111779061,
        "utf8_decoding_byte": 291580479,
        "utf16_decoding_base": 3543313050,
        "utf16_decoding_byte": 163577493,
        "sha256_base": 4540970250,
        "sha256_byte": 24117351,
        "keccak256_base": 5879491275,
        "keccak256_byte": 21471105,
        "keccak512_base": 5811388236,
        "keccak512_byte": 36649701,
        "ripemd160_base": 853675086,
        "ripemd160_block": 680107584,
        "ecrecover_base": 278821988457,
        "log_base": 3543313050,
        "log_byte": 13198791,
        "storage_write_base": 64196736000,
        "storage_write_key_byte": 70482867,
        "storage_write_value_byte": 31018539,
        "storage_write_evicted_byte": 32117307,
        "storage_read_base": 56356845750,
        "storage_read_key_byte": 30952533,
        "storage_read_value_byte": 5611005,
        "storage_remove_base": 53473030500,
        "storage_remove_key_byte": 38220384,
        "storage_remove_ret_value_byte": 11531556,
        "storage_has_key_base": 54039896625,
        "storage_has_key_byte": 30790845,
        "storage_iter_create_prefix_base": 0,
        "storage_iter_create_prefix_byte": 0,
        "storage_iter_create_range_base": 0,
        "storage_iter_create_from_byte": 0,
        "storage_iter_create_to_byte": 0,
        "storage_iter_next_base": 0,
        "storage_iter_next_key_byte": 0,
        "storage_iter_next_value_byte": 0,
        "touching_trie_node": 16101955926,
        "promise_and_base": 1465013400,
        "promise_and_per_promise": 5452176,
        "promise_return": 560152386,
        "validator_stake_base": 911834726400,
        "validator_total_stake_base": 911834726400
      },
      "grow_mem_cost": 1,
      "regular_op_cost": 822756,
      "limit_config": {
        "max_gas_burnt": 200000000000000,
        "max_stack_height": 16384,
        "stack_limiter_version": 1,
        "initial_memory_pages": 1024,
        "max_memory_pages": 2048,
        "registers_memory_limit": 1073741824,
        "max_register_size": 104857600,
        "max_number_registers": 100,
        "max_number_logs": 100,
        "max_total_log_length": 16384,
        "max_total_prepaid_gas": 300000000000000,
        "max_actions_per_receipt": 100,
        "max_number_bytes_method_names": 2000,
        "max_length_method_name": 256,
        "max_arguments_length": 4194304,
        "max_length_returned_data": 4194304,
        "max_contract_size": 4194304,
        "max_transaction_size": 4194304,
        "max_length_storage_key": 4194304,
        "max_length_storage_value": 4194304,
        "max_promises_per_function_call_action": 1024,
        "max_number_input_data_dependencies": 128,
        "max_functions_number_per_contract": 10000
      }
    },
    "account_creation_config": {
      "min_allowed_top_level_account_length": 32,
      "registrar_account_id": "registrar"
    }
  },
  "transaction_validity_period": 86400,
  "protocol_reward_rate": [
    1,
    10
  ],
  "max_inflation_rate": [
    1,
    20
  ],
  "num_blocks_per_year": 31536000,
  "protocol_treasury_account": "near",
  "fishermen_threshold": "340282366920938463463374607431768211455",
  "minimum_stake_divisor": 10
}
```

looks like `storage_amount_per_byte` is right there under `runtime_config` as expected.

#### conclusion

not sure what's going on with your code but this seems to work just fine for me

Comment: Thanks!  i found the solution i will post the answer.